# Async HTTP Client loads too much data?

Tags: java, android, http, android-studio, http-post

After I executed this request I only receive this message in my logcat:

`V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 47 from 1 (4700%)`

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    client.post("http://staglay.com/test.php", params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res) {

                    System.out.print(res);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("ASYNC-HTTP-REQUEST", "FAIL");
                }
            }
    );
```

Does anyone know why it is loading too much data or shows that it has received 4700%?

Also it does not `System.out.print` the result.
Can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: Use Log.d rather than System.out.print

Comment: @gaurav4sarma you definitely saved my evening, thank you!

Comment: I have posted it as an answer please accept it as an answer and upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Log.d rather than System.out.print

Comment: Thank you so much glad i was able to help